# Show loading screen and inflate layout

Tags: android, performance, layout, loading

I have a complex layout. So I want to show a loading activity(or any screen) meanwhile the layout inflates, And when the layout finishes inflation, the loading activity dismisses and the inflated layout is shown.

i have searched long for this but couldn't find a suitable answer.

thank you!

Comment: it is not possible at least due to the inflation is done in the UI thread while loading screen is showed in UI thread as well. You will end up with frozen loading screen while your layout is inflating. What you should do is to optimize your layout

Comment: Are you talking about Splash screen or just want to show a ProgressBar

Comment: @MeLine splash screen would do

Comment: @DibyaranjanMishra splash screen won't solve your problem.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko ok then...so is there no way?? .

Comment: the correct way is to optimize your layout. During 6 years of my Android dev experience I have never seen a layout which can't be optimized to load at least OK on most part of the devices

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thanx for your support .Can you suggest some source where I can learn about optimising layout and all. I am new to android and was just playing with layouts . My layout consists of : a nav drawaer with 2 fragments,one of those contains a bottom nav with 4 buttons and a Umano sliding up panel. which contains a view pager